# Site participation of users from smaller communities

Tags: discussion

I have been on Stack Overflow for almost a year and I think I now have a reasonable understanding regarding how the site operates. During my short journey on here I could not help but notice that there might be some bias towards participation of users from smaller communities.

In more popular tags such as [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) there is greater competition between answerers but at the same time there are *considerably more* opportunities to answer questions. In contrast, in other tags (e.g. [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) where I primarily participate),  there can be days before a question is posted. And even then it is not guaranteed that the question will be on-topic or answerable!

The consequence of this, is that it may take years for users in such tags to reach the ‘trusted user’ level, which will allow them to fully participate in the site. And this will be irrespective of their engagement level. In contrast, dedicated users in top tags can reach this threshold potentially even within a year! In addition, some badges that are (correctly) designed to be hard to get (such as Epic and Legendary), are pretty much unattainable if the user does not participate in top tags.

I am really curious to know what the reasons are that earned reputation does not take into account the *relative* contribution of the user?

One could argue that dedicated users in [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) make a greater contribution to the site but this is not necessarily true. I think for my primary tag I do contribute significantly and I would contribute even more if I could. And I suspect that this is the case for many other Stack Overflow users.

Comment: How would you measure relative contribution? I'm mostly active in OpenGL with 3-5 questions a day. But most of the questions are also tagged Java or C++ to indicate the language. Which tag counts now?

Comment: I know people who do better contribution on the site by simply editing posts to make them better, voting on bad posts to close them, comments on some to improve them, always in the review queues, etc etc

Comment: @BLD this should be decided by the community but an idea would be to ask the user to specify a _primary_ tag and then a number of secondary ones? These could then have different weights when calculating reputation.

Comment: The system treats rep as a measure of how well the user can be trusted to know how the site works.  Giving him access to increasingly more powerful but potentially destructive tools.  That just doesn't have anything to do with the size of a tag community, it is roughly proportional to how often you interact with the system.  Yes, averaging one contribution per day is the slow road, but you are doing pretty well so you'll no doubt get there.

Comment: @HansPassant rep is proportional to how often you interact with the system but has nothing to do with how many questions you can answer on the site? That does not sound reasonable to me. Expertise is indicated by the tags. I can theoretically answer in other tags but i do not have the expertise so i am limited to my tag.

Comment: This is not about technical expertise at all.  Again, it is about how well you know the system.

Comment: @HansPassant I respect your view but again this does not make sense to me. Reputation is the basis for participating on SO and you cannot indicate that you can be trusted more if you cannot increase your reputation. This can only happen if you can answer questions but by definition you are limited by your expertise, which is indicated by the different tags.

Comment: It will make sense to you some day, but you got to learn how the system works first :)  Fwiw, the site founders never claimed that they came up with the perfect way to do this, but it has turned out pretty well over the past decade and nobody found a better way yet.  I've seen it occasionally go wrong, users that earn large amounts of rep very quickly.  But then making very regretful decisions later, often to burn out badly and never come back.  Well, you don't have to worry about that.

Comment: @HansPassant There is no perfect way to do anything in life but because something works it does not mean that there is no room for improvement. Also, the extent to which a user knows how the site works (and hence can be trusted) is indicated by the badges. But these are not connected to privileges. The fact one has `x` number of gold/silver/bronze badges does not make any difference to site participation. :-)

Comment: @PearlySpencer: "*this should be decided by the community but an idea would be to ask the user to specify a primary tag and then a number of secondary ones? These could then have different weights when calculating reputation.*" Stack Overflow has gained a great deal by *not* segregating its membership across fields of expertise. What you'd be talking about is exactly that. And that is not a road we need to travel.

Comment: @PearlySpencer, smaller tags have thier benefits too. They are more healthy than major ones. It is easier to make rearch when amount of questions is smaller, and easier to ask an interesting question, not asked before, which is worth that smb spend their time on it. Major tags are flooded with duplicates in disguise and non-researched questions. P.S. your contribution in [stata] is pretty impressive, thumbs up!

Comment: @NicolBolas This is one way to see it and i respect your choice. But i see it as an effort to provide smaller communities with an equal opportunity to site participation. _Actually, there is no need to segregate anything_. As i commented in one of the answers, folks that fixate on my comment about adjusting reputation based on tags (a simple idea, nothing more, nothing less), seem to intentionally miss the point that reputation should not dictate so much user participation in terms of moderation.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: Why are you surprised that people are fixating on the *only question* in your post? Everything before it was mere prologue. You asked a question, people provided the answer. If that was just "a simple idea", why were you "really curious" about it?

Comment: @NicolBolas You commented on my comment, not my question.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: @NicolBolas I was responding to your comment above with the 4 up-votes.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: Yes, I know that, but it doesn't change the fact that your post contained essentially the same idea: having "earned reputation" "take into account the relative contribution of the user". That's the central idea of your post. My point is the same either way; everyone on SO is part of one big community.

Comment: @NicolBolas The central idea of my post is that users in smaller communities cannot participate fully on SO unless they acquire the necessary reputation. Which is very difficult to do in non-top tags. Please do not conflate the two.

Comment: "How would you measure relative contribution?" One could probably find something. For example inverse weighting where the weight scales with the square root/logarithm/some other sub-linear dependency on the popularity of the contributed tag. The measure would surely be somewhat more complex to implement and kind of arbitrary and may depend on other things, but then, every measure is arbitrary.

Comment: Breaking SO apart into SO-C++/Java/Python/Javascript/Android and SO-"everything else" might be an idea.

Comment: What about the idea of  "You need an exam to pass to get this moderator privilege"? It will be not easy to implement and should be not easy to achieve but perhaps in this way the best people could reach the privileges without being hampered by their 'expertise' in a certain field. (Of course the actual 'rep award' method should remain in

Comment: The OP asserts that there is an inherent advantage to answering more popular tags.  This assumes the higher number of questions outweighs the decreased competition to answer questions.  There is, however, no evidence provided by the OP that this is necessarily true, as far as I can tell.  It certainly might be true, but it might not.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The system is quite flawed and it has always been that way.

- One major problem is that there's not necessarily any relation between technical knowledge and moderator suitability. Someone can post a few great questions or answers and suddenly they have all manner of moderator privileges.
- Another major problem is that there's not necessarily any relation between reputation and technical knowledge. If you participate in a low traffic tag, you will not get much reputation.

  If you look at our most [esteemed gurus](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=all) rep-wise, they are mostly participating in tags like Java, C#, Javascript or SQL. You can compare this with some unpopular language like lets say [Ada](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/ada/topusers). For all we know, the top user there might be as brilliant at Ada as Jon Skeet is at C#. The rep doesn't reflect this.

Unfortunately, the rep doesn't scale with how popular a tag is. If you look at other SE sites with far less traffic, they often lower the rep bar needed to gain certain privileges. But that's not easily done on SO, since it is such a mix of everything.

SO is built on top of this flawed system and it is probably too late to change it. A better system would give different rewards for moderator suitability and technical knowledge. For now, we just have to deal with it.

If you need to gain rep, you can either participate in some higher traffic tag or do edits (Approved edits give rep up to a max of 1000).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Instead of pretending that everything is fine, I think acknowledging the problem is the first step towards a solution. From the down-votes in my question i feel some people in the community are uncomfortable even with the idea that something is wrong. I totally agree with your suggestion to fully separate site participation in terms of moderation and technical input. As i have said previously, one way to do this is to give badges some power. Currently, they are only there for cosmetic reasons, which is a shame as I believe they could play a much more important role.

Comment: I have never heard of reviews giving rep. Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @AndréKool He probably refers to editing posts. If you are below the 2K reputation threshold you get +2 for each (accepted) edit.

Comment: @PearlySpencer He might also be thinking about the badges you can get for reviewing. Unfortunatly I can't read minds and because it clearly states _"I believe reviews give rep"_ I was asking about that.

Comment: many years ago Atwood suggested to adjust the system: [Replace accept rate with citizenship level](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/165179/165773) "What is more useful to the longer term health of a community: a single OK question, or an engaged community member who assists and participates — as a citizen, not just another drive by hit and run?"

Comment: @Vega Yes but this is the only case and it is also tied to reputation!

Comment: Indeed, I meant editing not reviewing, I had forgotten which one that gives rep. I believe the system caps out eventually.

Comment: @PearlySpencer It is the same problem with badges though, as you get them after at least 1000 score and posting at least 200 answers. That's going to be very hard to achieve in the Ada tag, not so much in the C# tag. The score and answers would need to be set according to tag traffic, but perhaps require a minimum tag traffic in order to get any badge at all.

Comment: @Lundin It is not the same. The Moderation badges do not depend on tags, they recognize site-wide contributions (as they should).

Comment: I editted the max rep you can get from edits (1000). I have to note that after you get 2k rep you won't receive any rep from edits anymore (with the exception of tag edits) because you get the edit privilege then.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Eh well, badges kind of do too. Personally I've somehow gotten a C++ gold badge, even though I'm hardly a C++ guru and avoid that tag. I have apparently only answered 154 pure C++ questions, not 200, most of them likely re-tagged C questions. I have however answered a lot more with C and C++ tags both, and so I got the C++ gold badge for general site-wide contributions. And also gold badges in "arrays" etc, so the site trusts me to be able to moderate/ have knowledge any topic about arrays, be it Ada code or Python code. So the badge system is quite flawed too.

Comment: @AndréKool Thank you for straightening that out :)

Comment: @Lundin This is not about the tag badges. It is about users from smaller communities participating in site-wide moderation. Let's not conflate the two.

Comment: How about instead of getting a gold badge with dupe hammer privileges etc. through gaining 1000 score on a tag, these privileges were awarded based on your patterns of voting to close questions that were eventually closed for these same targets (i.e. where other users agreed)?

Comment: So, basically what we need are better measures. Measures of moderator suitability (could be behavior in the review queues) and measures of technical knowledge within tags (could be a mixture of absolute and relative (or both)).

Answer (score 18):

> I am really curious to know what are the reasons that earned reputation does not take into account the relative contribution of the user?

Because that would make no sense.

Reputation, for the purpose of generating privileges, is essentially about answering the question, "can we trust that this person understands the system well enough to be allowed to do X?" Basically, reputation is used as a way of measuring how much the user understands about SO. This is not just about SE as a Q&A site, but about the SO community and its guidelines.

Let's say you have a user on a low-participation tag. Maybe the number of questions is so low that they can only answer one question a week. And maybe the number of users who frequent it is so low that such answers only attract 2 upvotes.

After a year of one-answer-a-week participation (and thus ~1000 rep), can you *truly* say that this user understands Stack Overflow just as well as a person with 10K rep? That is, a person whose contributions have been frequently and positively reviewed by lots of people.

Low participation means low interaction. And low interaction does not promote understanding how SO is meant to work. To understand how SO works, you need to participate on it significantly. And in a low participation tag, that will take longer than in a high participation one.

So this kind of grading on a curve just doesn't make sense.

Also, let's not forget that Stack Overflow is not segregated. It's not cordoned off into individual tags with fences or somesuch. If you have Trusted User status, you have Trusted User status, period. You can perform those actions on *any question*. That is the entire point of giving someone that status; they're "trusted" to act anywhere on the site.

A user who only frequents low participation tags cannot be trusted unless they've spent a long time on the site. A user who frequents higher participation tags will have higher engagement due to more interaction, and thus can be trusted to understand SO in less time.

Comment: Thanks for providing an answer to my question. But i totally disagree with you.  By equating total time of site interaction/participation with answering questions you commit a logical fallacy. Providing answers is the only way to increase the measure of trust which in this case is reputation. But there are users who spend _a lot_ of time on the site without answering questions all the time. I am one of them. These users participate in reviewing activities, editing work and interacting with the site in a way that is not always _directly_ measurable and reputation does not reflect that.

Comment: I fail to see why you know more about the site, just because you're active in a tag with more regulars. Writing the same amount of answers but getting way less reputation out of it doesn't mean that one knows the site less good.

Comment: @BDL: I never said it's a perfect measurement. But it is a measurement all the same. On high-participation tags, you will see questions get closed with greater frequency. As such, you will learn what should be closed. You don't get this experience nearly as quickly on low-participation tags. The same goes for editing and so forth.

Comment: @NicolBolas: I bet I can pinpoint a number of 20k+ users from high frequency tags having never done any moderation task/reviews. But it seems the site trusts them more than me with 13k and 3.7k reviews and an active meta participation.

Comment: I'm not sure that introducing a tag voting factor is a good idea, but I really don't like the argumentation that it shouldn't be done because participation in a high volume tag gives you better knowledge of the site.

Comment: @PearlySpencer: "*These users participate in reviewing activities, editing work and interacting with the site in a way that is not always directly measurable and reputation does not reflect that.*" OK, but what does that have to do with what you asked about here? Which was specifically about adjusting reputation gained based on tag participation. You're now talking about giving reputation for other forms of interaction. Are you saying we should *assume* that people on low-participation tags will also be doing these things?

Comment: @BDL: "*I really don't like the argumentation that it shouldn't be done because participation in a high volume tag gives you better knowledge of the site.*" You can like it or not, but it's still true. More interaction with users gives you experience, and high-participation tags give you more interaction with users. It's hardly a guarantee, but there's a fair likelihood that those 20k+ users who've never done moderation tasks at least know *how* to do them.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Then let's say we disagree on that.

Comment: You do not have to assume. Badges provide an indication but these are not connected to privileges or reputation. And what i said was about adjusting reputation to reflect the contribution from answers. Site participation such as voting and other activities is linked to reputation earned from providing answers. But one cannot answer questions in the c# tag if s/he does not know anything about this language. That does not mean that someone does not participate in the site in other meaningful ways.

Comment: Just to clarify "_...Site participation such as voting and other activities..._" refers to voting to close/reopen questions, delete posts and the like not  merely voting on questions and answers.

Comment: @PearlySpencer "These users participate in reviewing activities, editing work and interacting with the site in a way that is not always directly measurable and reputation does not reflect that" - so isn't this more of a question of getting reputation for those things then? If not, how would you tell the difference between someone who only pops in once a day to post an answer and someone who also posts one answer a day, but also does moderation tasks for a few hours a day, in the same tags? And why would doing that in a small community be better than doing it in a big community?

Comment: @Dukeling No this is not about getting more reputation from these things. This is about having the privilege of doing these things, which currently depends on reputation. Please see my other comments for elaboration.

Comment: @Dukeling The entire point of my question is that site participation in terms of moderation should not be so tightly connected with reputation from technical input. Yet it is the latter that decides the former. Folks that fixate on my comment about adjusting reputation (a simple idea, nothing more, nothing less) based on tags seem to intentionally miss this point.

Answer (score 7):

If "trusted user" means "master of a niche tag" then sure.

> I am really curious to know what are the reasons that earned reputation does not take into account the relative contribution of the user?

That is a nice question, but I believe the point of reference is a little bit off. Low traffic tags are, as implied, low traffic. While an answerer has a higher importance relatively to that specific tag, it is of much lower importance in regard to the whole site.

If, and only if, moderation privileges were given on a tag basis (as in, close questions in the tags you have score in) then yes, adjusting reputation accordingly to the tag traffic could make sense, but moderation privileges apply to the whole site.

If anything, adjusting reputation in accordance to tags traffic ought to earn *less* reputation in lower traffic tags, to make for the relative "un-trustiness" of a user who have not been part of a major part of the site.

I posit that trusted user does not mean "understands the playgroud of that specific tag(s)" but rather "understands the playground of that specific site".

Comment: And your assumption is that someone from a major tag with 25 answers at 10 knows more about the site than one with with 200 answers in a low traffic tag with 0-2 upvotes? As I already said in the comments of the other answer: Reputation has almost nothing to do with how well you know the site and it's features. I can easily show you some 20k users who have never done any reviews. But they are trusted enough to delete answers, while, for example, I'm not trusted enough to do so although I did 1000s of answer reviews.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. You bring up some interesting points which further beg the question: _should site participation in terms of moderation be so interconnected with reputation?_ I believe it shouldn't because it discriminates against smaller communities. Also, note that weighting reputation is only one potential way of addressing the problem (and by far the best). Indeed, how much total reputation a user would gain would depend on the implementation details of such a scheme so your post only describes _one_ potential outcome.

Comment: @DBL Oh, assuredly, reputation is quite broken in that regard. I agree with Lundin answer, and your argument here. In the *current paradigm* however, where we don't just throw the very meaning of reputation out, then I think than yes, being more in contact with more people will make a user more aware of the site's dynamics. Be it only because they are being made aware of more moderation actions. Talking more with people, interacting more with people, does make one more aware of the site, yes, and that happens more in higher traffic tags.

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: But you aren't in contact with more people just because you participate in a high volume tag. Actually, you might have read and seen way less questions with the same rep.I don't think that adjusting rep is a good idea. But the problem that results from the coupling of reputation and privileges is, that moderation in low-volume tags is terrible. When you have 3 regular contributors, non of them able to delete anything, then terrible questions don't get handled unless you write to SOCVR.

Comment: @BDL exactly my point. And adjusting reputation was just an idea, not sure why so many people fixate on this.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I understood that as your primary question, which is also why I've quoted it. Maybe I erred or misunderstood, but the structure of your question does seem to lead to it, making it some kind of "primary point", and not just some kind of idea :)

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier No problem :) My question was about site participation and I threw the idea of adjusting reputation in the context of the current system where reputation is closely linked with privileges. I think a better approach is to separate these two. How this would be done is an entirely different question.

Comment: what about templeos gold badge? I want mine

Answer (score -17):

**Completely agree with @OP (= @Pearly Spencer)'s Qt...**

**=> A few Solutions/Answers for @OP's Qt:**

- First, the Rep_Req=50 for posting a Comment is useless for "New" Users: **Allow at least a Credit of 10 Comments, until Rep_Pts=50...**, with either each '+1' on a Comment = +1 Rep_Pt or = +1 Comment Credit until 50 has been reached...

New Users (with low Rep) can only post an Answer but not a Comment, I don't get it...!? (And anybody can edit some other Qt/Post/Answer from anybody else...!? I would expect at least 500 Rep_Pts for that..., ah but OK, => +2, hum..., I'll join the Club then..., now I understand why all Qt's always get edited by sbd else, ah-ah...! Pff..., a bit fake, sorry...!)

- **Some (Advanced) Moderators could review from time to time the Threads in the "low traffic" Tags, and add us a few '+1' + force an 'Accept Answer' when it's obvious that the Answer provided was the "correct" Solution and the @OP simply didn't bother to follow up** once they got their Answer and their Script working...
- And I actually quite like the System of choosing 1-2-3 "Main" Tag(s) (at least for "Answerers") that sbd in the Thread mentioned, that could count x2/x3 for the '+1', especially for Answers in 'low traffic' Tags, as the whole Site is more "designed" for "Askers" than for "Answerers"...

**Qualify Users on the Site as 'Asker' and/or 'Answerer', with more Rep_Pts earnt as 'Answerer'...** (And prevent one single User from downvoting all Answers from another User because they don't like being asked to mention their Config, ah-ah...!)

> > >

I'm also (only) active (well was, until I quickly got "silenced") in a low-traffic Tag ([imacros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/imacros)), with about 3-5 Threads per week, very often from first time Posters on SOF, Users who don't really know how the Site works with "+1" and accepting the Answer, so they quickly disappear once they've got their Solution and their Script working...

On the other "hand", I run the 'iMacros' Forum on the iOpus/Ipswitch Site as Moderator, so I guess I'm a bit of an "Advanced" User and I usually can answer 95% of all possible Threads...

On the iMacros Forum, I (en)force Users to give a Descriptive Title to their Thread (=> "HELP/URGENT/HELP"... etc doesn't work!, ah-ah...!), + mention their FCI (Full Config Info), + follow up neatly on (all) their Thread(s), and + share their Sol/Final Script.

I tried to do a bit the same on SOF to improve the 'Quality' of 'iMacros' Threads on this Forum when I started to answer Threads, but quickly got all my Sols/Answers for "other" Threads downvoted to 0 or negative from a few Users who didn't like me asking about their FCI...

> > >

OK, that was it, not sure what the 'community wiki' CB means below my Post, I don't check it... Now let's see if I was correct that I still had 1 Answer-Credit, otherwise, I typed this for nothing, ah-ah...!
[The 'You have no more Credit' should actually come **before** typing a Comment/Answer, and not once we try to post it... (One of the main Reasons why I didn't try to answer any Threads anymore, the 'Comment' and 'Answer' Buttons should simply be disabled if we don't have any "Credit" anymore or not enough Rep_Pts, got fooled several times, then I gave up...)]

Comment: i have no idea what this answer-credit is that you seem to put emphasis on or what a CB is that you mention users should be forced to select in your comments

Comment: (Sorry, Double Post and I have to hurry up, "Comments can only be edited for 5 min"...:
Oh, Thanks @Memor-X, you are the first to put a Comment...
Well you can only post 5 Answers, until you've reached I don't know what Rep_Pts Threshold, not mentioned when you try to post the 6th Answer...
"CB" = "Check-Box"..., meant for some 'community wiki' CB just below posting an Answer, no Idea what it is meant for...

Comment: i am unsure of any answering limitation outside of answer bans but if there is one it sorta sounds like it's apart of the [New User Restrictions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/new-user) which is automatically removed after 10 rep. also you might benefit by looking at the other privileges as everyone and suggest edits to other people's posts but these then have to be approved by 2 other higher rep users. you need 2,000 rep to edit without approval

Comment: also assuming Qt is Question Thread, understand that this isn't a forum but a Question and Answer site. people post Questions and others post Answer to those questions where each and every answer posted but attempt to answer the question they are replying to. also the number you are seeing is the score which is the total number of up/downvotes which help determine quality in the main sites and also agreement/disagreement on Meta. each user can only vote once per post so moderators can't *"add us a few '+1'"* and only the question asker can make the Accepted Answer, no one else

Comment: Ah OK, the 'Accept Answer' was indeed one of my Suggs, as I mentioned, many Users (at least on the 'iMacros' Channel) are very often first time Posters, they don't do the '+1' and 'Accept Answer', then we as "Answerer" remain with an Answer Vote=0, while it is the complete Solution, and we can do it 5 times, until we've reached the 5 Answers... and can't post anymore...

Comment: By "Qt", I meant just "Question"... (+ "Pb" = "Problem") Sorry, I thought those were "Standard" Abbreviations for TechSup Sites/Forums... Hum, and "OP" = "Original/Opening Post" (in a Thread) while "@OP" = the "Original Poster" (= usually the Starter of the Thread)...

Comment: Hum, about the "New User Restrictions", I don't think they really apply to me, I think I joined SOF about 2 maybe 3 years ago, I can't find any Date in my Profile, and I don't see any Date either about when those 'NUR' were posted/made applicable, ah-ah...!

Comment: Stg I don't understand, I went from '0' on this Answer, with 40 Rep_Pts, now I'm already at '-7' (oops...!), but my "Rep" went from 40 to 50 Rep_Pts..., how come...!? (Now I can post a Comment somewhere, woaw...! + A Badge, oh-oh...!)

Comment: Hum, already at '-8' and "my" Answer + all Comments are now some light blue Colour, looking like 'Disabled', but I apparently still can post a Comment...

Any chance one/all the "major" Actors in this Thread could react to my "Answer"...?
=> Pearly Spencer + BDL + Hans Passant (hum, you, don't trust much, ah-ah...!, but at least explain why you give me an extra '-1') + Nicol Bolas + @Lundin + André Kool + Félix Gagnon-Grenier
(Can only 1)

Read my Answer till the end, always 'verbose", sorry, can't understand I only get '-1' x8 or x10 now probably, with no explanation from anybody...

Comment: @chivracq: Voting on meta doesn't affect your reputation.

Comment: Ah OK, Thanks @BDL, still doesn't explain why my Rep then went from 40 to 50 Pts, but OK, never mind...

Any "Feedback"/"Comment" on my "Answer" maybe...? (As it now has '-10' and nobody cared to explain why they voted '-1'...)

Comment: Feedback) General things first: The post is very hard to read. SO does not encourage you to write in internet slang. Write full english sentencens,
don't use too much punctation ("...!?", "...,"). Don't missuse formating features (like separators with `>>>`) Don't use abreveations that are not common. Don't rant. SO doesn't have threads. It has questions. Try to make a clear point in your answers. Don't hide it behind hundreds of other things.
(All of this also applies to your other answers on the main site).

Comment: Feedback) Content: You are mixing several things together. Comments have a minimum rep to prevent spam. Allowing 10 comments would completely defeat the purpose.
"Moderators review low quality tags": Given that SO has ~7k questions a day, reviewing all questions in all low volume tags sounds like a hugh amout of work. Noone expect for the op can set the accept mark.
Moderators are not tag experts, so how should they know if an answer is good.

Comment: "Before I got silenced....": Use answers only to answer questions.
Don't ask op to improve their question in an answer. Don't use them to reply to other answers. Also, you don't know who voted on what. It might be that you get downvoted because you ask for FCI, it could also 
be completely unrelated. "You have no more Credit": There is no such thing as a credit on the site. There are some
quality bans, but I'm not sure if you mean that.

Comment: @BDL, bit late, sorry... OK for "General things first" part... About 'Comments', 50Pts needed to be able to post a Comment i.e. ask OP for which Version they are using. Only "way" is to post a (fake) Answer (before posting a "real" Answer), and you can only post 5 Answers in total... I had to delete several of my (real) Answers (because low Tag, low quality/first time Users who don't accept Answers and never come back) to reuse my 5th and last Answer x times... (Now after playing "strategically" the "SO Game", finally managed to pass 50Pts Threshold, and more "relaxed" now...)