# Are questions about "how to ask" off topic on SO?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Came across this question today: [How to ask high quality reproducible questions in Stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53438117/how-to-ask-high-quality-reproducible-questions-in-stata)

I do appreciate the effort the OP has put in and both question and answer seem to be well thought out, helpful and garnering upvotes.  However, it's left me a bit confused though since it's not related to programming and almost certainly opinion based. Checking in with the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I don't really see how it's on topic.

Is a question like this off-topic for Stack Overflow?  Does it belong here on Meta? <s>Is there a precedent for similar "how to ask" questions having a place on SO?</s>

As the OP pointed out, his question was inspired by the likes of:

- [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)
- [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

So apparently there is some precedent - just never noticed those before.  I'm still curious as to how any of these, despite being highly upvoted, are on topic.

Comment: It's a try for providing a canonical. Not a really great one tho.

Comment: There are similar questions for the pandas and R tags. Not sure what you are after here.

Comment: @Pearly I'm not saying that the q&a is or isn't on-topic, but that there are **other** similar questions doesn't mean this question is actually on-topic. If you believe other off-topic questions exist, VtC those.

Comment: @yivi I do not think they are off-topic. The OP here thinks they are.

Comment: @Pearly I only say that because you commented on the existence of similar questions. That's not relevant. Other questions may or may not exist, but that's not a valid defense on the topicality of this particular question.

Comment: @PearlySpencer - I never said that.  If I thought yours or any of them were off topic I would have voted to close/downvoted - which I have not.  Instead I have come here asking for guidance and at the moment I remain somewhat neutral.

Comment: @yivi We need a question / answer like this because the info in the help center is generic and not tailored to Stata. Most new askers have no idea about how to generate data in Stata  or how to debug their code using Stata's commands.

Comment: Sigh.  This isn't about helping anybody to ask questions, it is an excuse to close them.

Comment: The question was migrated to [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/how-to-ask-high-quality-reproducible-questions-in-stata), apparently.

Comment: @Pearly I haven't voted on any of the linked questions in any way, but I could see how someone could say than the other examples are a tad more focused and practical than this one. Not saying that they shouldn't be migrated as well (or that any one should have been migrated), just saying that the questions are not **identical**.

Comment: @yivi The only difference between the questions is that the others are in more popular tags. I couldn't care less about my question being migrated but IMO this is additional proof of a double standards mentality and bias towards smaller communities.

Comment: @HansPassant does that excuse for closing them apply to only the example under  scrutiny or all provided examples?

Comment: I'm not sure what the final result of this process is going to be, but as the creator of one of the affected questions, I want to point out that if these questions become harder to point new users to, it will *seriously* impact the experience for regular answerers in [r] and [pandas]. Trying to get new users to include data in their questions is a daily battle in those tags, and data-based questions are extremely hard to answer without examples. I enjoy helping out new users with R, I don't enjoy constantly pleading with them to include their data in the question.

Comment: @Marius this is also the case for the Stata tag. Yet the Stata question was the only one migrated. We can still link directly on Meta so it is not a total disaster... Can you not do the same in the **R** and Pandas tags?

Comment: I guess so. My main concern would be existing links to the questions breaking, and users who know these questions exist trying to link to them but failing to find them if they search "[pandas] reproducible"

Comment: Unfortunately, I think the "*daily battle (of) ... constant pleading to include data in their questions*" pretty much applies to all tags on Stackoverflow.  While those posts are very useful resources to offer a quick link for new users, I don't really see how those topics can possibly be any more newb ridden than others here.  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you guys, but it really sounds like there is a feeling that these tags specifically are some kind of special needs case.

Comment: @billynoah Yes, you do misunderstand what this is about. This is not about the number of newcomers. This is about providing specific advice to newcomers. Stata, **R** and Pandas do not have the same commands to generate data, debug etc with Java and C++.

Comment: @billynoah I realise it's hard to get new users to include code examples and the information needed to understand them, but it's *even harder* to get them to provide a usable example of the data they're working on in an R/pandas/Stata data analysis, that's what is unique to these tags.

Comment: Ok, as someone who knows absolutely nothing about any of those tags I will defer to your first hand experiences.  I can only say that I would describe the things I encounter elsewhere precisely the same way so on the surface at least, it sounds very much like a universal problem.

Comment: Close reasons are means, and not ends in themselves. If we agree that questions of this sort are useful resources for our task of curating questions, and that they should exist somewhere around here (i.e. either in the main site or in Meta), we should first examine whether the choice of place has any effect over the usefulness of such questions, before entering an abstract discussion about topicality.

Comment: Side q: is flagging links to such "questions" in comments encouraged in the same way as very similar links to "I downvoted because" site or requesting MCVE in comments?

Comment: @PearlySpencer The Stata question was the only one migrated because it's the only one that *could be* migrated. [Questions that are older than 60 days old can not be migrated, even by moderators](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work). The other two questions are dramatically older than 60 days. Thus, neither can be migrated. If you're interested in the reasoning behind the 60 day limit, you might read: [Disable migration for questions older than 60 days](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/151890/disable-migration-for-questions-older-than-60-days).

Comment: @Makyen  I am aware of the posts and anyone who reads them carefully will see that this policy was instituted to curb migration of crap posts on other Stack Exchange sites which created conflict. In this case, we are talking about very helpful questions with hundreds and thousands of up-votes. Let's not use a policy created with good intentions as an excuse not to give a **fair** solution here.

Comment: @PearlySpencer It's how the system is currently designed, not just policy. Only an SE employee can migrate something > 60 days old (I have no idea if there's limits on which SE employees can do so, so it may be a *very* small number of people). You appear upset that the other questions have not already been migrated, because, you claim, "**that's not fair**", when the situation is dramatically different for the other questions, and it's quite possible that no one who *could do* the migration is aware that some people desire it done (the employee being willing to migrate is a different issue).

Comment: @Makyen This is not a real argument. Common sense says that the system can change if necessary and SE moderators/employees have the power to make anything happen. This is not about me. This is (again) about Stata users and users from smaller tags being treated differently than those in more popular tags. I have been accused about  not open to ideas and now being upset but quite frankly I have yet to hear a convincing argument from anyone here about how those questions are different than the Stata one.

Comment: @PearlySpencer You're taking this personally. No, this is not about "Stata users and users from smaller tags being treated differently" (BTW: nice inflation of the group to fit your agenda/perceived prejudice). This is about a question that's 2 days old being treated differently than ones that are 5 years old and 7 years, 6 months old. That's it. That's the only reason they're being treated differently. If the Stata question was > 60 days old, then it would have been treated just the same as the other two. If the other two were < 60 days old, then they would have been migrated too.

Comment: @PearlySpencer If you want the migration policy to change, then make a feature request post requesting that the policy be changed.

Comment: @Makyen I am not taking anything personally. And the rest is clearly your interpretation. The community can't have it both ways. Move something when it suits, keep something when it does not. Your argument about the other two questions simply does not make sense in this case. To me at least.

Comment: @Makyen If you read the comments below you will also see that there is no personal agenda here. The top contributor of the Stata tag fully supports my views and in fact has contributed to the Stata question. Nice try though.

Answer (score 26):

In a word - **yes**. This question isn't about programming, but about how to ask a good question on Stack Overflow. As such, it doesn't belong on Stack Overflow itself, but here, on Meta Stack Overflow.

Comment: This question is not about how SO operates as a whole. It is about improving programming questions from new askers with specific advice for Stata users. Nevertheless, if the community decides that this kind of questions are off-topic then ALL similar questions should be closed and moved on Meta.

Comment: @PearlySpencer:  Questions about how SO operates as a whole *and* questions about how to ask on SO are welcome here on MSO.  After all, asking good questions is one of the ways that SO operates.

Comment: I support @Pearly Spencer strongly here, both on general grounds — although I would not object if such threads were **all** placed on Meta — and specifically as someone active on the Stata tag. This is a focused effort to provide a resource packed with constructive advice. It’s already been found useful.

Comment: I like what Pearly wrote and I agree that all of these types of questions belong here on meta.  At the very least they need to have an officially designated home.  Unfortunately it appears the others are "too old to migrate" so not sure we're going to arrive at any consistency here.

Comment: @NickCox you can support them all you like and still be wrong. These questions are absolutely off-topic on the main site and on-topic here. The fact that a question has not yet been moved is not evidence of anything other than the fact that it has not yet been moved. Unfortunately both questions are too old to be migrated. So moving them would require deleting the ones on main and recreating them here.

Comment: @TinyGiant I suggest that "absolutely" off-topic can only mean that no one well informed about SO could possibly disagree. FWIW, not much I know, I disagree.

Comment: @NickCox You can disagree as much as you like, you'll still be wrong. It's blatantly off-topic for Stack Overflow, and anyone well informed about SO would know that.

Comment: That's not an argument: there is no logic and no evidence to what you're saying, just an assertion of a personal view that you're repeating. I note that the R and Pandas threads show evidence of thousands and hundreds of upvotes, so many, many people following those tags feel extremely positive about them. On whether you're better informed than I  am about SO, I leave that open.

Comment: @TinyGiant Accusing two other users with considerable reputation and moderation experience that they are not well informed on the ways of SO because they disagree is pretty telling. Furthermore, one can hide behind the _too old to migrate_ label but the fact that the two other questions on SO remain open shows the blatant bias towards smaller communities. Hypocrisy at its finest.

Comment: There is a "stata" tag on SO, but not on meta, right?  It can't make sense to have hundreds of these sorts of language specific things on meta can it?

Comment: IMO, the practical consideration is that for the stata (R, pandas, etc) you need to access this Q&A from the wiki.  Or should this Q&A instead be part of the wiki?

Comment: Seems like a classic case where straightforward reading of SO rules (which Pearly & Nick generally love to enforce in my experience ;-) means it should be on meta, but in this particular case, everyone is pretty clearly better off if this question is left on SO.  We have moderators so that some common sense exceptions can be made, right?

Comment: @Nick Upvotes have no relation to topicality. Off-topic questions get upvoted all the time. To put it in another light, how is it a programming question or a question about the use of a programming tool for programming purposes? It's not, it's a question about how to ask questions on Stack Overflow, which should be on meta, not on the main site. My assertion was that anyone familiar with the topicality of Stack Overflow would be able to identify the fact that it is not a programming question, nor a question about the use of a programming tool for programming purposes, and that it is off-topic.

Comment: @JohnE The only thing I can "enforce" is closing of Stata questions as duplicates given a gold badge. Otherwise like almost everybody else I depend on others agreeing with me.

Comment: @TinyGiant I will be hearing next that the thousands of upvotes I mention are "fake votes". I am just citing them as evidence that many people can implicitly be happy that a thread is on-topic.

Comment: @NickCox I didn't say they were "fake votes". I said _"Upvotes have no relation to topicality"_. Close votes are used to indicate topicality, upvotes are used to indicate that a question "shows research effort; it is useful and clear". Those are two very different metrics.

Comment: You're welcome to your own phrasing of your own views, naturally. I'll leave it there.

Comment: @NickCox Notice that I quoted the exact text from the upvote tooltip there. This isn't my own phrasing, it is the phrasing used by Stack Overflow. See also: [Old highly upvoted questions that don't follow current SO standards](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/306273/old-highly-upvoted-questions-that-dont-follow-current-so-standards)

Comment: How to create a reproducible example *is* on topic for Stack Overflow. It is a programming task after all. Details that makes this question specific to SO questions make it more suitable for Meta but I don't think closing the other two questions (especially the R one, after [Will's revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/5963269/2)) is constructive.

Comment: @ayhan so how to create a reproducible example is on-topic but how to create a reproducible question is not? i am genuinely curious

Comment: @PearlySpencer Creating a reproducible example is a programming task entirely. Writing a good question that contains a reproducible example is not. One is broader, more conceptual and the other one is more technical. I wouldn't be strongly against moving all of them to Meta by making them less technical but apparently it is too late to migrate the other two questions and even community moderators cannot migrate them so closing them seems destructive to me.

Comment: @ayhan I somewhat disagree here. IMHO a good question to be reproducible needs not only a reproducible example, but good technical writing which requires variable names and commands in the code to be free of typos, the OP to provide debugging code trace where necessary and all the other things i go through in my answer. I guess I have a more holistic approach but I see your point.

Comment: @NickCox My point was that if you wanted to make a case for topicality, you could do something like [examine the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5963269/timeline) and extract the [closure related events](https://gist.github.com/Tiny-Giant/90204e5f4c5651fccda592d0e3549cf2). Upvotes aren't a good metric to use for making a case for the topicality of a question because they have no inherent measurable relation to topicality. An upvote can have so many other meanings than "this is on-topic", close votes _only_ mean "this is not on-topic". Users can upvote well before they can close vote.

Comment: I think these types of posts fall between the two sites and prob should be left on main and possibly locked, with a link to the tag wikis. Main has more visibility and the posts can be tagged with the tag people are posting under. So they're searchable with that tag.

Answer (score 6):

The posts predominantly discuss how to created reproducible examples of code. They sit somewhere between both Stack Overflow and Meta. The people who would be searching under those tags are less likely to find those posts on Meta. They may not be aware meta exists. They will more likely to find them under the tags.

This question [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) is tagged [r-faq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r-faq).

Linking these posts in the tag wiki and leaving them on SO is the better option. This way they remain searchable  under those tags.

The [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) wiki has been updated to include the relevant post.

The two posts still in the main site are locked as community wikis. No more answers can be added, but the existing answers can be edited.

None of this is set in stone. The posts do not need to stay on main.

Comment: If the other two questions are not be moved on Meta then the Stata question should be moved back on SO. Would you not agree that this would be the fair thing to do? Or Stata users are inferior somehow?

Comment: @PearlySpencer do you want it moved back?

Comment: Yvette, with all due respect this is not about what I want. I simply think this is the right thing to do for Stata users and users of smaller tags in general. Despite the uproar, I have yet to hear a convincing argument from anyone about how the Stata question is different from the R and Pandas ones.

Comment: Thanks for contributing another point of view.  I'm honestly surprised that there is no clear consensus about this

Comment: Frankly none of the arguments made here are valid arguments for keeping a question on main that doesn't belong on main. I'm not convinced that the other two need to be moved (as ayhan said producing an MCVE _is_ a programming task where asking a question is not), but I'd like to see some valid arguments on the matter. A question is not on-topic on main because _"The people who would be searching under those tags are less likely to find those posts on Meta. They may not be aware meta exists. They will more likely to find them under the tags."_ otherwise every meta question should be put on main

Comment: @TinyGiant A good reproducible question on _statistical programming_ requires more than just an MCVE in the traditional sense. In this respect, there is no real difference between the Stata question and the other two. But if it helps I have now re-worded the Stata question to more closely resemble the other two.

Comment: @PearlySpencer That doesn't matter. The task of producing an MCVE is a programming task. The task of producing a question is a question asking task.

Comment: @TinyGiant We clearly disagree.

Comment: @PearlySpencer The Pandas example is quite a bit more on the question asking task end of things, whereas the R example is specifically about the programming task of creating an MCVE.

Comment: I personally think that if we could come up with a standardized format for what a good "How to ask questions in X tag" format and start posting them on meta under a common tag, then start linking to them and showing that there would be a _global_ use for such a feature, that would make a much better case for the creation such a feature. As opposed to just having overly broad, controversial posts spread across the main site with no standard format for what one should look like, what information they should or should not contain, or how they should be handled by the community.

Comment: @PearlySpencer Sure, in this case you have made a high quality example, but if such a question is to be allowed on main, how do we handle _low-quality_ examples that occur in the wild? What about examples in low traffic tags? In a controlled environment such as meta, it is much easier to handle problems when they occur at the scale of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @TinyGiant But this is not what you are arguing for. What you are arguing for is keeping the other questions on the main site but the Stata one on Meta. Again,  both as a scientist and statistical programmer I disagree with the core of your assertions. An MCVE may be enough for a [html]  or [css] programming problem but not for a good reproducible programming question where the end goal is statistical analysis.

Comment: @PearlySpencer, no I said twice that I was not convinced that either of the target questions should be moved. That isn't arguing _for_ keeping them there, it is explicitly not providing and argument that they should or should not be moved and saying because I'm not convinced either way. I think that if a question is about producing an MCVE then it is on-topic and that if it is about producing a question then it is off-topic.

Comment: @TinyGiant Sorry but you are just repeating the same argument over and over again with different words. So I am going to leave it at that.

Comment: I'm using different words because you don't seem to be understanding what I'm trying to say. I'm saying that I don't know if those other two examples should be moved or not. _I think_ that the pandas question is off-topic on main, I don't know whether it should be moved or not because doing so would have a lot of side-effects and I'd rather leave it alone until someone smarter than me figures out how to fix the problem in a manner that considers all of those side effects. I don't think the R example should be moved because it is about producing an MCVE, not producing a question. @PearlySpencer

Comment: @TinyGiant tbh I'm not sure which is the best place for these types of posts. Either way I'm not fussed and I don't think it matters that much, if we can come to some agreement.

Comment: @YvetteColomb The place is not important to me either. What is important to me is that all questions be treated fairly. That said, any suggested solution should be pragmatic. The suggestion to create a place on Meta to host such questions is pure fantasy. Other more urgent issues are overlooked every day. This suggestion will not be implemented in 100 years.

Comment: @PearlySpencer I agree. I'm not sure what to do at this stage. I'm waiting for feedback from other mods. Timezones and all that :)

Comment: **Moderator note:** comments seem to be going somewhat off track here folks... Let's keep 'em for what they're for in relation to the answer please.

Comment: Can you please replace the "great R" words with "minimal" in the R question (as we can't edit it anymore)? Also, I think it's kind of unfair this question is being closed as OT without the option to reopen it. Some people (including you) do think it's on topic but can't express their thought anymore. I also think that linking to this question and telling new users to learn from it how to write an on-topic question while this same question is closed as OT is confusing. I generally don't have problem with it being locked, but the irreversible closing is what seem unfair/counter-intuitive.

Answer (score -2):

In any discussion of this kind it is important to keep in mind that **some opinion** is unavoidable, both in science and life in general. Stack Overflow is no
exception.

Personally, I think that a **reproducible programming question** needs more than just providing a reproducible example. As I explained in a comment here, I strongly believe that a question, which aims to be useful not just to the OP but also to  other users, **additionally requires** good technical writing, code comments,  variable names and commands in the code to be free of typos, debugging code trace where necessary and so on. This is particularly true for questions where the end goal is the **statistical analysis** of data. In general, high quality reproducible programming questions should include all the things I go through in my ["How to ask" post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377015/).

Perhaps I should had given to the question part a bit more technical flavor. However, in the above context, I still think that my question (and the two others after which it is modelled) adheres to Stack Overflow's on-topic policy. I suppose I have a more holistic approach, which clearly is not shared by everyone here. And that's fine. **In a democracy everyone is entitled to his/her own opinion.**

The community I think was too strict in enforcing this policy and voted to
migrate my question but **I am perfectly happy with that.** The idea was always to create an one-stop Stata resource for newcomers and convert this to a wiki post once a stable form was achieved. This question is necessary to give **specific** advice to newcomers in [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) and provides **practical** examples using Stata's programming language. The [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) links are useful but are more general and a bit too long so new users typically do not make an effort to read them.

However, strict interpretation and enforcement of the on-topic policy is not the
only problem in this case. Another problem is the **selective enforcement**. Either all similar questions should be closed and moved on Meta Stack Overflow or none. The only real difference of the Stata question with the ones in [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r) and [pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) is that the latter are in more popular tags.

The argument that the other two questions are **too old to be migrated** would make
sense if the migration concerned another Stack Exchange site. [This policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) was primarily instituted to curb migration of low-quality questions towards other Stack Exchange sites, which created conflict. In this case, we are talking about very helpful questions moved on Meta Stack Overflow. Let us not use a policy created with good intentions as an excuse not to give a fair solution here. The fact that the other two questions remain on the main Stack Overflow site, in my opinion, provides further proof of a double standards mentality and [**bias towards smaller communities**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/372450/site-participation-of-users-from-smaller-communities).

In accordance with the principles of **equality** and **fairness**, the other two questions should be moved by the site moderators/owners on Meta and until that happens they should stay closed (but not deleted). **Alternatively, the Stata question should be moved back on the main site**.

Comment: +1. I *routinely* point users to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Perhaps 25% of users take it on board. *That's not a bad success rate* given the poor starting points. I don't mind where the post sits, but if it gets more visibility on SO main, it may work well there. Enhanced tag wikis have been requested before, but [**that won't happen**](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314089/what-does-constructive-criticism-of-a-design-change-look-like/314348#comment1030131_314348).

Comment: linking them in the tag wiki is helpful. I don't think migrating them to meta is a good idea. There's in a no man's land somewhere between the two sites. They are more visible as @jpp said on main.

Comment: @YvetteColomb We will but the problem with the tag wiki is that new users for whom this post is intended never read it.

Comment: @PearlySpencer we definitely need a feature to bring tag wiki's in front of the eyes of new users.