# How to create high quality reproducible examples in Stata

Tags: discussion

After having spent more than a year answering questions in the [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata), it is clear to me that the vast majority of people asking questions here are mostly new or occasional users of Stack Overflow. Such users are more likely to confuse this site with a traditional forum such as [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/) and post unclear or off-topic questions.

These users typically:

1. Have little familiarity with Stata's interface and language conventions asking questions that can easily be answered by consulting a help file
2. Ask how to do something without providing any context
3. Dump an unformatted code snippet with no comments, cryptic variable names and typos
4. Fail to provide realistic data examples
5. Neglect to describe what results they expect

The motivation for this question has been the success of similar questions for
[Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/) and [R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/) in providing a one-stop beginner's resource. The examples provided there from experienced users appear to have increased the chance of (new) askers getting answers to their questions.

What is your advice for creating a high quality [stata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stata) reproducible example?

Simple datasets can be entered with the `edit` command, which opens the
variables editor and allows the user to manually type or paste data.

Programmatically, the `input` command can also be used:

```
clear

input id str5 name income
1 "Tracy" 90000
2 "Ramon" 70000
3 "Kevin" 80000
end

list

     +---------------------+
     | id    name   income |
     |---------------------|
  1. |  1   Tracy    90000 |
  2. |  2   Ramon    70000 |
  3. |  3   Kevin    80000 |
     +---------------------+
```

Are there any additional tips to using `input` for providing example data?
When should one use the `trace` and `pause` commands? What other information
should be included?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### Congratulations on seeking help for your Stata programming problem!

Acknowledging that you need the input of others is the first step towards
resolving it and maturing as a Stata user/programmer. Writing a good question is not a trivial task and requires experience. The latter comes with practice, which in turn requires perseverance.

The secret in writing a high quality reproducible Stata question is the
successful creation of a sandboxed example. This should use the shortest
possible snippet of code and the minimal amount of example data required to
replicate your problem.

Stack Overflow's Stata volunteers are always happy to help but they do not spoon-feed. Lack of effort from your part will make it less likely that you get an answer and increase the chance that your Stata question will be closed and ultimately deleted.

---

### Tips for improving your question

> You can add this thread in your list of favorite questions by clicking the star ⭐ on the left hand side above. This will allow you to easily access these tips again from your profile's favorites tab.

#### • I am new in Stata and I do not know its commands yet

Before posting a question, please make sure that you have read *Getting Started
with Stata*. You can access these introductory manuals by typing `help gs` from Stata's command prompt.

There is simply no replacement for acquainting yourself with the basic concepts
and syntax of Stata. This is particularly important as effective communication requires you to be able to speak the same language as the other more experienced Stata users on Stack Overflow.

Do not forget that these users want to answer interesting programming problems,
rather than act as tutors for teaching the basics. A more general forum such as [Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/) or [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/stata/) may be more appropriate for problems relating to basic command usage.

#### • I want to do [something] in Stata and I need the code

Stack Overflow is geared towards solutions for *specific* programming problems. It is thus important that you explain as clearly as possible your situation and show us what you have tried.

1. Start by clearly stating your question and telling us your Stata version and platform (Windows, Mac, Linux).
2. Then give some context. This should focus on succinctly describing in words
   both your dataset and what you are trying to do.
3. Next tell us how you attempted to accomplish your goal. This stage includes
   attaching the code that you used and the produced output. You should also link to any similar questions that you consulted on-line.
4. Finally provide us with example data to run the code and reproduce your problem. These data should not be shown using a screenshot! See further down for help on this step.
5. Always respond to comments requesting clarification from potential answerers.

#### • I have this code in R/Python/SAS/SPSS and need the same in Stata

Questions asking how to translate code from other languages to Stata's `ado` or
`mata` languages are only valid if and only if there is a *specific* problem to be 
addressed in the attempted Stata code. Consequently, all the items listed in the previous and next sections are also relevant here.

#### • This is the Stata code I used but it does not work

1. Check for typos *both* in the script *and* in the code snippet provided in your question. The Stata interpreter is unforgiving: what might seem a straightforward programming task can thus quickly become an exercise in frustration. Stata volunteers on Stack Overflow are not here to hunt down typos arising from careless typing.

   Example:

   ```
   locla mymacro HELLO
   genrate var = 5
   ```

   ```
   local mymacro HELLO
   generate var = 5
   ```
2. It is best to *not* abbreviate commands and avoid eliminating all
   white-space. This makes code harder to read and it is more error-prone. Other
   inexperienced users may also find it difficult to recognize even basic commands.

   Example:

   ```
   forval i=1/5 {
   loc mymacro`i' HELLO `i'
   g var`i'=`i'
   }
   ```

   ```
   forvalues i = 1 / 5 {
       local mymacro`i' HELLO `i'
       generate var`i' = `i'
   }
   ```
3. Do not post your entire `do` file or code segment, but only the problematic part. In addition, make sure you properly format your code using code blocks. If your code snippet is more than five or six lines, break this into sections if necessary. Where the names of the variables you use are not self-explanatory, please provide comments.

   Example:

   sysuse auto
   des
   sum mpg
   gen mempg=r(mean)
   gen smpg=r(sum)
   reg mpg weight length

   ```
   /* load data */

   sysuse auto
   describe

   /* descriptive statistics */

   summarize mpg
   generate mean_mpg = r(mean)
   generate sum_education = r(sum)

   /* regression analysis */

   regress mpg weight length
   ```

4. Make sure to check the help file for clues on why your code fails. Problems are often caused by invalid syntax. You can access the help files for commands and functions by typing `help command/function name` in Stata's command prompt.

   Example:

   ```
   list, separate(0)
   option separate() not allowed
   r(198);
   ```

   Here, typing `help list` reveals that this is not legal syntax. Indeed, the name of the option is `separator(#)` and not `separate(#)`.

5. Try to debug the code on your own before you ask here. Stata has useful debugging commands such as `set trace` (see `help trace` for more details), which shows how the code executes in real-time. Another useful debugging command is `pause`, which temporarily suspends execution of the code (`help pause` for more information).

   Example:

   ```
   set trace on

   forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
       display `i'
   }

   - forvalues i = 1 / 2 {
   - display `i'
   = display 1
   1
   - }
   - display `i'
   = display 2
   2
   - }
   ```

   Use these commands if your problem is not an obvious syntax error and include in your question *selected* relevant output, which is likely to shed more light on the causes of the problem. In addition, always include the *full error code and message* that Stata reports.

6. If you are using a *community-contributed* command that you have 
   downloaded from SSC, the *Stata Journal* or another source, it is important that you indicate this early on in your question. In this way, people who might answer do not waste time looking for it in external sites and can more quickly identify problems related specifically to this command.

#### • Here is a screenshot of my Stata dataset

Please do not upload screenshots!

[image]

Screenshots are not as helpful as you hope, primarily because they do not allow people who might answer to copy and paste data into their own Stata and try to reproduce the problem.

In addition to the `edit` and `input` commands outlined in the question part of this thread, there are *four* other ways you can provide example data for your Stata question.

1. If your data is confidential, you can demonstrate the problem using the `sysuse` command to load one of Stata's toy datasets:

   ```
   sysuse dir
   auto.dta         bplong.dta       brand2.dta       bsexper3.dta     census.dta     
   auto2.dta        bpwide.dta       bsexper1.dta     cancer.dta       citytemp.dta    
   autornd.dta      brand1.dta       bsexper2.dta     cearep.dta       citytemp4.dta

   sysuse census, clear

   list state region pop marriage in 1 / 5

      +---------------------------------------------+
      | state        region          pop   marriage |
      |---------------------------------------------|
   1. | Alabama      South     3,893,888     49,018 |
   2. | Alaska       West        401,851      5,361 |
   3. | Arizona      West      2,718,215     30,223 |
   4. | Arkansas     South     2,286,435     26,513 |
   5. | California   West     23,667,902    210,864 |
      +---------------------------------------------+
   ```
2. Alternatively, you can directly download an [online example dataset](http://fmwww.bc.edu/gstat/examples/) with the `use` command:

   ```
   clear
   use http://fmwww.bc.edu/ec-p/data/wooldridge/vote1

   list district voteA expendA shareA in 1 / 5

      +-------------------------------------+
      | district   voteA   expendA   shareA |
      |-------------------------------------|
   1. |        7      68     328.3    97.41 |
   2. |        1      62    626.38    60.88 |
   3. |        2      73     99.61    97.01 |
   4. |        3      69    319.69     92.4 |
   5. |        3      75    159.22    72.61 |
      +-------------------------------------+
   ```
3. For examples with your current dataset use the `dataex` command:

   ```
   dataex mpg price foreign in 1 / 5, elsewhere 

   ----------------------- copy starting from the next line -----------------------
      * Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
   clear
   input int(mpg price) byte foreign
   22 4099 0
   17 4749 0
   22 3799 0
   20 4816 0
   15 7827 0
   end
   label values foreign origin
   label def origin 0 "Domestic", modify
   ------------------ copy up to and including the previous line ------------------
   ```

   In this case, the first five observations of variables `mpg`, `price` and `foreign` are requested. Note the option `elsewhere`, which is explained in the help file for `dataex`.

   Copy and paste everything between the end lines and use the `{}` button in 
   the Stack Overflow question editor to format the snippet.

   The `dataex` command is especially needed when:

   - We need to be clear on whether a variable shown as text is really a string variable or a numeric variable with value labels.
   - You have date variables, which otherwise can be very awkward for people who might answer to handle.

4. You can also use several other Stata commands and functions to simulate data:

   ```
   /* generate data in wide form */

   // discard data in memory
   clear

   // set the number of observations in dataset
   set obs 6

   // create a simple identifier
   generate id = _n

   // set the random-number seed for reproducibility
   set seed 12345

   // create a uniformly distributed random variable with values between 0 and 1
   generate var1 = runiform()

   // create a normally-distributed random variable with mean 20 and standard deviation 5
   generate var2 = rnormal(20, 5)

   // create random indicator variable 0/1
   generate var3 = rbinomial(1, 0.5)

   // see the results
   list, separator(0)

      +---------------------------------+
      | id       var1       var2   var3 |
      |---------------------------------|
   1. |  1   .3576297   22.72038      0 |
   2. |  2   .4004426   20.00814      1 |
   3. |  3   .6893833    21.7884      1 |
   4. |  4   .5597356   29.39434      0 |
   5. |  5   .5744513   33.77373      0 |
   6. |  6   .2076905   16.93702      1 |
      +---------------------------------+
   ```

   ```
   // optionally create value labels for numeric variables such as id above

   label define idlabel 1 "one" 2 "two" 3 "three" 4 "four" 5 "five" 6 "six"
   label values id idlabel

   list id, separator(0)

      +-------+
      |    id |
      |-------|
   1. |   one |
   2. |   two |
   3. | three |
   4. |  four |
   5. |  five |
   6. |   six |
      +-------+
   ```

   ```
   // create (random) date variables
   clear
   set obs 6

   // a daily date numeric variable
   display date("25/11/2018", "DMY")
   21513

   generate var1 = 21513 + _n

   // a random date variable within a specified interval
   generate var2 = floor( ( mdy(12,31,2018) - mdy(1,1,2017)+1 ) * ///
                          runiform() + mdy(1,1,2017) )

   // a half-yearly date numeric variable
   display yh(2018, 1)
   116

   generate var3 = 116 + _n

   // see the raw results
   list var1 var2 var3, separator(0)

      +----------------------+
      |  var1    var2   var3 |
      |----------------------|
   1. | 21514   21004    117 |
   2. | 21515   21351    118 |
   3. | 21516   21529    119 |
   4. | 21517   21532    120 |
   5. | 21518   21104    121 |
   6. | 21519   21523    122 |
      +----------------------+
   ```

   ```
   // see formatted results

   format %tdDD/NN/CCYY var1
   format %tdDD/NN/CCYY var2
   format %th var3

   list var1 var2 var3, separator(0)

      +----------------------------------+
      |       var1         var2     var3 |
      |----------------------------------|
   1. | 26/11/2018   04/07/2017   2018h2 |
   2. | 27/11/2018   16/06/2018   2019h1 |
   3. | 28/11/2018   11/12/2018   2019h2 |
   4. | 29/11/2018   14/12/2018   2020h1 |
   5. | 30/11/2018   12/10/2017   2020h2 |
   6. | 01/12/2018   05/12/2018   2021h1 |
      +----------------------------------+
   ```

   ```
   /* generate data in long form */

   clear
   set obs 9

   // create an identifier increasing every three observations
   egen id = seq(), block(3)

   // create a year variable within each id
   bysort id: generate year = 2015 + _n

   // create a normally distributed random variable within each id
   bysort id: generate var = rnormal()

   // calculate the sum of var within each id
   bysort id: generate sum_var = sum(var)

   // note here the use of the `bysort` prefix, which sorts data and repeats
   // the command for each group of observations

   // see the results by id
   list, sepby(id)

      +-----------------------------------+
      | id   year         var     sum_var |
      |-----------------------------------|
   1. |  1   2016    .1973079    .1973079 |
   2. |  1   2017    1.610224    1.807532 |
   3. |  1   2018   -.8034225    1.004109 |
      |-----------------------------------|
   4. |  2   2016    1.096012    1.096012 |
   5. |  2   2017   -.4407027    .6553089 |
   6. |  2   2018   -1.011427   -.3561177 |
      |-----------------------------------|
   7. |  3   2016    1.019227    1.019227 |
   8. |  3   2017    1.871976    2.891204 |
   9. |  3   2018    .4235664     3.31477 |
      +-----------------------------------+
   ```

#### • Stata does not produce the results I want

You should always include the output from Stata in your question. This should be copied and pasted directly from the Stata console. Then select the pasted output and click `{}` in the question editor.

Example:

[image]

```
. sysuse auto
(1978 Automobile Data)

. regress price mpg i.foreign

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        74
-------------+----------------------------------   F(2, 71)        =     14.07
       Model |   180261702         2  90130850.8   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   454803695        71  6405685.84   R-squared       =    0.2838
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.2637
       Total |   635065396        73  8699525.97   Root MSE        =    2530.9

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         mpg |  -294.1955   55.69172    -5.28   0.000    -405.2417   -183.1494
             |
     foreign |
    Foreign  |   1767.292    700.158     2.52   0.014     371.2169    3163.368
       _cons |   11905.42   1158.634    10.28   0.000     9595.164    14215.67
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

If Stata gets back to you with unexpected results, it is most likely because it was not programmed correctly. Stata simply does what the user instructs it to do.

That said, users on Stack Overflow are not mind-readers. Providing an example of the desired output will greatly increase your chances of getting a helpful response.

If it is a graph, you can post a picture that illustrates the outcome. 
Otherwise, a table with an adequate amount of expected results is best.
This can be generated using an online table creator (such as [Table Generator](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/text_tables) or [ASCII Table Generator](https://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/)) and pasted in your question appropriately formatted in code blocks.

Example:

Country Population Mean_age Sex_Ratio GDP
United States of America 3999 23 1.01 5000
Afghanistan 544 19 0.97 457
China 10000 27 0.96 3400

```
+--------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+------+
|                          | Population | Mean_Age | Sex_Ratio | GDP  |
| Country                  |            |          |           |      |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+------+
| United States of America | 3999       | 23       | 1.01      | 5000 |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+------+
| Afghanistan              | 544        | 19       | 0.97      | 457  |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+------+
| China                    | 10000      | 27       | 0.96      | 3400 |
+--------------------------+------------+----------+-----------+------+
```

### Examples of high quality questions

The following questions can be considered as good examples of how you should structure your own Stata-related programming question:

- [Change order of text in variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52721745/change-order-of-text-in-variable-names)
- [Axis labels off-center when broken over multiple lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48563533/axis-labels-off-center-when-broken-over-multiple-lines)
- [Equivalent of Stata macros in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51619884/)
- [Getting coefplot to use estimate titles or outcome labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45831575/getting-coefplot-to-use-estimate-titles-or-outcome-labels)
- [One-liner for wrapping some text around members of a list of numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52088929/one-liner-for-wrapping-some-text-around-members-of-a-list-of-numbers)

### Further advice

It is crucial that you also read the following pages on Stack Overflow:

1. [Site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)
2. [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)
3. [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Finally, you may also find helpful the information on the [Statalist FAQ](https://www.statalist.org/forums/help).

Comment: Excellent. Some small suggestions edited in.