# How to ask a good ggplot question downvoted and put on hold

Tags: discussion, specific-question, scope, community-wiki

I often find questions with the `r` and `ggplot` or `lattice` tags that are cluttered with irrelevant information about formatting of the plot.

If the user is asking about an error message, or looking to align two components of the plot, we don't need to have information about text formatting, font setting, color setting, and the like.

That irrelevant information goes **in excess** of what is really a *minimal reproducible example* (emphasis in *minimal*), and thus distracts the potential answerer from what really matters, and will eventually bring traffic that is irrelevant too (maybe related to the formatting).

Thus I wanted to "clone" this very successful thread: [How to make a great R reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), of which there are many analog for the different languages / tags. The cited example has, at the time of this writing, 2474 votes (only 8 negatives), and its accepted answer has 1621 votes. Most of its 20+ answers are well above 100 points.

I tried to reproduce the original post as much as possible, and the resulting post is here: [How can I ask a great ggplot / lattice / base plot question?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747471/how-can-i-ask-a-great-ggplot-lattice-base-plot-question).

The question was initially well received, with edits by some users and some upvotes, both in the question and the answer (a wiki answer). However, it has been recently downvoted and put on hold on the ground of being "opinion-based".

Of course it is opinion-based! **All the questions** of this type are opinion based. The post I used as reference reads:

> What are your tips for creating an excellent example? How do you paste data structures from r in a text format? What other information should you include?

How is that **not** opinion based?

I don't want to be heavily downvoted in a post I put trying to help with the quality of questions... I see that indeed my post is opinion based, but it is just as opinion-based as the many more of the same vein that exist as reference in the platform.

If there's a real reason to keep it on hold (or to be downvoted), I'll be glad to delete it altogether. I would like to know your opinion (yes, this is opinion based too).

Comment: i mean... This is more an argument of why the highly voted one should be closed, however we mere normal users can't do so.

Comment: Why are these posts on main in the first place?

Comment: Looking at the revision history, you can see that in november of last year, there was a closure and a reopening, locking, etc, so there was some discussion on this particular post in the past, somewhere.

Comment: I feel like the entire R post should be migrated here to Meta, since it's a question about how to do something on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Looking at the timeline of that R post: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5963269/timeline I have the feeling there has been a meta post that is now deleted. Or that frigging SOCVR room has been playing tricks again. Nope, not in their transcript ...  no blame today

Comment: I don't know if moving it to meta is actually a good move... You could check there's a link to that question in many poor questions that are later edited and improved. If it were on meta, new users couldn't access it, could they?

Comment: Seems more like a question better suited for here in meta rather than main SO.

Comment: @PavoDive New users can't post on meta (outside of certain special cases) but there's nothing stopping them from reading it. Both this and the original are clearly meta questions.

Comment: doing a little bit of [late] research, I found https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples to be closed as off-topic. I guess there's a lot of house keeping moving that kind of questions to meta, then

Comment: if it needs to be on main, it could be edited into the tag wiki.

Comment: it needs a mod to see if there is a prior now deleted meta discussion on it. That panda's post got locked in the same timeframe as the R one

Comment: I found it: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/377011/are-questions-about-how-to-ask-off-topic-on-so and the consensus seems to be that they are OK-ish ...

Comment: Oohhh... I take back my suggestion to move the question here to Meta, it would break over [4000 links in comments alone](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1079241/count-of-comments-containing-links-to-the-r-reproducible-example-guide).

Comment: @DavyM: Unless I'm terribly mistaken, moved posts leave redirects behind. Moving them wouldn't break anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's ok to attempt to do what you are doing. Perhaps mod flag to have it made a community wiki next time.

In the meantime, I reopened your post and made it a community wiki. I also [left a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56747471/how-can-i-ask-a-great-ggplot-lattice-base-plot-question#comment100865021_56747471) for future reviewers:

> **Mod Note:** This post is intended to be a canonical post to assist new users. Please see [How to ask a good ggplot question downvoted and put on hold](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/387493/how-to-ask-a-good-ggplot-question-downvoted-and-put-on-hold)

Thanks for making that effort to improve the site.

Comment: I don't know who's the mode that made this decision. The post is opinion based, and is a dupe of what the OP already linked to. There's already a canonical post to assist new users, just read it through.

Answer (score 4):

These questions aren't programming questions.
They're meta questions **about how to ask** programming questions.

As such, these should be moved to Meta.

Comment: tbh it was never clearly decided where they should be. I am not really sure. I don't mind either way, it would be good to have a consensus. The advantage of main is they can have the programming language tag

Comment: I don't think the language tag outweighs having off-topic questions on main.